# jquery animate background-size onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I'm working on a Wordpress site (it's in "coming soon" mode so I can't give a link) where the client wants a background image to zoom slightly. I figured I could achieve this easily with CSS animation, manipulating the background-size. It worked great!... except in Safari and IE.

Why not use an image and set the z-index and use scale(), you ask? Well, they only want the background on one post. And that means 'post', not 'page', otherwise I'd just set up a new page template and be done. It forced me to specify the background image on the individual post body class (body.postid-23.custom-background {...}).

So I need a way to animate the background-size, without hovering or clicking, as soon as the page loads. Anyone do this before? Any help is appreciated. I'm not a javascript/jquery coder, but I can use them well enough to make it work for my sites.

Comment: Please choose any of the answers as "accepted" if it has helped you to help others with similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want:

```
$(function() {
    $("yourSelector").animate({
        backgroundSize: "100px 100px"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will fire once the page has finished loading.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Not sure if you require the code in the middle aswell?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `document.ready` function in this way :

```
$(document).ready(function) {
    $("selctorOfYourBackgroundImage").animate({
        backgroundSize: "100px 100px"
    });
});
```

As soon as the DOM has finished loading, the animation will occur!

Comment: I put this in the header file. How does the animation work? What does the "100px 100px" refer to? Is there a start and finish size? How about duration? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: 100px 100px refers to height and width .. And put the script at the bottom of the page.. After all the code of body finishes.. And u can give other parameters too.. Which i think u can google it?

Comment: I still didn't get it to work, but I had to switch to another project. Thanks for your help. I'll be back soon.